# Executing multiple instances of script - GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing

I am currently attempting to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), however I am not being successful at it. Installation was pretty easy. My goal is to run two parallel instances of python script [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) with its corresponding arguments. What would be the proper way to execute the script using parallel?

Parallel

```
parallel 'youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video1.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/stun-gun-used-on-man-in-police-custody-dies-lawsuit-dnt-brown-tsr.cnn"' 'youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video2.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/5-year-old-saves-family-from-house-fire.ktla"'
```

It works if run the command seperately without parallel:

```
youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video1.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/stun-gun-used-on-man-in-police-custody-dies-lawsuit-dnt-brown-tsr.cnn"

youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video2.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/5-year-old-saves-family-from-house-fire.ktla"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For just two streams, it would be easier just to put an ampersand (&) at the end of the first command and you are all done. Like this:

```
youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video1.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/stun-gun-used-on-man-in-police-custody-dies-lawsuit-dnt-brown-tsr.cnn" &
youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video2.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/5-year-old-saves-family-from-house-fire.ktla" &

# Wait for both downloads to finish
wait
```

If you want to use GNU Parallel... something like this - though I normally get told a better way.... :-)

Create a file called `work.txt` that contains this:

```
/media/video1.%(ext)s http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/stun-gun-used-on-man-in-police-custody-dies-lawsuit-dnt-brown-tsr.cnn
/media/video2.%(ext)s http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/5-year-old-saves-family-from-house-fire.ktla
```

Then the command would be:

```
parallel --colsep " " youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o {1} {2} < work.txt
```

Another option would be to simply put your two commands in a file and send that to `GNU Parallel`'s standard input like this:

Store this in `work.txt`

```
youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video1.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/stun-gun-used-on-man-in-police-custody-dies-lawsuit-dnt-brown-tsr.cnn"
youtube-dl -w --no-warnings -o "/media/video2.%(ext)s" "http://www.cnn.com/videos/us/2015/11/11/5-year-old-saves-family-from-house-fire.ktla"
```

then just run

```
parallel < work.txt
```

Comment: Great detailed answer. I was able to replicate and now it works succesfully.